# Issue changing column names when using Spoon/Kettle

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm using Spoon (version 8.2) and I'm having an issue changing column names in a MySQL Query.

For example, if I use this query:

```
Select
col1 AS ID,
col2 AS Name
...
FROM mytable;
```

It returns rows with the original name without rename the columns as I set above. I tried the same with a mysql server and with a mariadb server but I get allways the same result. I've updated the connectors too.

However, in a SQL Server connection it works perfectly.

Could anyone tell how to solve this problem? What could be going on?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly I am also facing same  trouble in mysql .Try this instead execute sql script in spoon to alter the column name.